# Istotope plugin - filters with second level of tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

For a project with students I would like to filter projects with Isotope plugin.

I'm trying to filter projects with two levels of filters.

The user can choose only one filter for the first level and only one filter for the second level.

The first filter level work fine but not the second level (for `mémoire` and `sujet libre` categories). When the user choose a tag in the second level nothing is happening.

Here is the page : http://www.labonneboite.fr/isotope/

And my code with isotope plugin :

```
var grid = $('.isotope-list');

grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry'
});

var filters = [];

$('.isotope-button').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);

    var isActive = target.hasClass('status-active');
    var filter = target.attr('data-filter');

    var filterInactive = [];
    $('.isotope-button.status-inactive').each(function() {
        filterInactive = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        removeFilter(filterInactive);
    });

    if (isActive) {
        addFilter(filter);
    } else {
        removeFilter(filter);
    }

    grid.isotope({ filter: filters.join(',') });

});

function addFilter( filter ) {
    if ( filters.indexOf( filter ) == -1 ) {
        filters.push( filter );
    }
}

function removeFilter( filter ) {
    var index = filters.indexOf( filter);
    if ( index != -1 ) {
        filters.splice( index, 1 );
    }
}
```